# Our pilot lost the logbook

Tags: faa

Our company pilot lost the aircraft logbook for about 15 years worth of flights.  Boxes of stuff.  Who knows how he lost it.  We now want to sell the aircraft - can FAA reconstruct the logbooks?  If costs are involved can we get the pilot to pay for it?

Comment: The FAA doesn't get copies of your logbook periodically, so they can only vouch for registration data or if a major repair/STC were performed (337). The linked question by fooot is good, basically you need to do a very thorough annual and have an A&P verify that all the AD's are complied with (which may require tear-downs). This can be very expensive. As for getting the pilot to pay for it, that is something your lawyer is going to have to answer.

Comment: Plan on getting about 50% the blue book value of the plane *if* you can even find a buyer.  You can try to make the pilot pay for it but you'll spend a lot of money on that with a pretty good chance that the pilot will never be able to pay you back even if you are successful in securing a judgement. Find those books.  What kind of plane is it?

Answer (score 4):

> We now want to sell the aircraft - can FAA reconstruct the logbooks?

As @fooot mentions in the comments you can [find most of the details on this question here.](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/2484/what-happens-when-the-logbook-of-an-aircraft-is-lost) There is a [brief AOPA article here](https://www.aopa.org/news-and-media/all-news/2000/january/02/lost-logbooks).

> If costs are involved can we get the pilot to pay for it?

For this you need to consult a lawyer (I would try and get one that specializes in aviation related cases). Depending on how his contract (if he has one) with your company is arranged you may have some weight here. There is a [nice document covering a lot of cases in this space that you can find here.](http://www.coolinglaw.com/Content/UploadedFiles/Documents/Articles/Aircraft%20Logbooks%20.pdf) See section VI, but you may be covered for this under your insurance,

> **VI. LOST, STOLEN OR DESTROYED LOGBOOKS
>   MAY BE COVERD UNDER THE AIRCRAFT'S
>   INSURANCE POLICY.**
>
> Lost or destroyed logbooks may be covered under the aircraft’s
>   insurance policy. However, whether or not coverage exists will depend
>   on the language of the policy and, if the logbooks are not
>   specifically covered under the policy, an insurer can deny coverage
>   and a court may have to decide whether coverage exists.

I would seriously take time to look for them prior to doing anything as Im sure you already have. You can take a look at this thread for [some info on rebuilding logs.](https://www.pilotsofamerica.com/community/threads/lost-log-books.35450/)

It is also worth reaching out the aviation shop that you use to maintain the plane. Many shops may have work records on file that can help you rebuild your records.